# Two of the same foreign key from the same table into another table?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, foreign-keys

Is it ok to have two columns in a table that can be a foreign key from the same table?

For example:

I have an 'address' table with columns:
id, street, city_id, state, country (or id, street, city_id, state_id, state_id)

I have a 'states' table that hold state and countries:
id, name, level

So can I put states_id in state and country of the address table (as in the brackets above)?

Comment: Can you show a few sample rows from your `states` table? If the state implies the country then you don't need (and don't want) a `country` identifier on your `address` table.

Comment: I haven't created the table yet. I am just thinking of the design. But yes, it would have countries and some subdivisions there too (but not all, I will get users to input subdivisions as and when they come). Each entry will have an ISO3166-1 for the country, as well if need be, an ISO3166-a2 for the states (that could also appear in the iso3166-1 list).

Comment: ...for example, the usa, has puerto rico as a subdivision, UK has wales, china has taiwan (which appears on both). So I would filter out the possible inputs for state and country by reading the states table differently.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's totally OK.

Ed Gibbs's is right, don't do that if the state implies the country.

In your exemple, maybe it would be better to split the table in two distinct tables for clarity, say `State` and `Country`, but from a general point of view, there's no problem with this practice.

This case (2 FK in a table both referencing another table) often happens, for example in a `messages` table, with a `sender` and a `receiver`, which both would reference to the same `users` table.

Comment: Thats exactly the kind of situation I'm looking at, and I will face your example too.